# What are the steps for mobile game character after sculpting?

Tags: modeling, baking, polycount

I am currently working on a mobile game character, so performance is important. I have a kind of reference that I use for inspiration:

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/christmas-present-shooter-ea8304e3b7ee443aa11e05c2add45348

The model has very few vertices but pretty nice details:

[image]
[image]

And here's my model:

[image]

I am new to this field and I am confused even after watching many tutorials. I have a feeling I have to bake the details of the high resolution mesh and use it on the low poly mesh but the process is unclear so far. I have seen tutorials that retopologise the high sculpted mesh, then subdivide it many times, then bake those details. But that did not seem to work for me because many details of my model are lost but the poly count is still high.
So my question is, what are the steps, how can I achieve the kind of look on the reference, with many details but low poly count?

Here's my high poly version:

[image]

And my low poly one:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you need to create a low-poly version of your object, but you need to do it manually to get a good topology, then bake the normals of your high-poly on the low-poly to add fake 3D details that you could not do on a low-poly

Comment: Hm yes, but what are the steps for that? RIght now I have a high poly, sculpted mesh and I did the retopology, so I have the low poly version too. But for example how do I bake the sculpted version's normals? For example if I now want to bake the HP version, I cannot, because "No active UV layer found in the object", and I am not surprised of that, I expected it but how do I unwrap such a high poly mesh?

Comment: you don't need to unwrap the high-poly, you need to unwrap the low-poly. Also maybe show how your low-poly looks like?

Comment: Sure, I'll include them in the question. Also I'm sorry but I am really confused as to how to tell blender that I want the Head_HP object's normals to be baked on the Head_LP. I'm sure it's really easy but for some reason right now I cannot seem to put it together in my head, I've never done this before.

Comment: you have a lot of tutorials about the baking process: basically you need to select the high-poly, shift select the low-poly and bake. The low-poly needs to be unwrapped, you need to create a new Image Texture in its material, etc

Comment: side note there is this function "tris to quads"

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it! I have some problems still but I will write those down in another question.